# What is meant here by "content switch threshold" and does this make FF faster?

Tags: performance, firefox

On this page of [Firefox-speed tips](http://www.techradar.com/news/software/applications/8-hacks-to-make-firefox-ridiculously-fast-468317)(a little dated, 2008), it says:

> If you haven't moved your mouse or touched the keyboard for 0.75
>   seconds (the content switch threshold) then Firefox enters a low
>   frequency interrupt mode, which means its interface becomes less
>   responsive but your page loads more quickly. Reducing the content
>   switch threshold can improve performance, then, and it only takes a
>   moment. Type about:config and press [Enter], right-click in the window
>   and select New > Integer. Type content.switch.threshold, click OK,
>   enter 250000 (a quarter of a second) and click OK to finish.

What's meant by this "content switch threshold"  - like switching tabs, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The setting is documented in MozillaZine (the first result when I google for "firefox content.switch"](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Content.switch.threshold).

The documentation says Firefox's parser can be "interrupted" at a greater frequency which makes the UI more responsive but means that less time can be spent (in a given time range) for document parsing, so the page will load slower (from the user's perspective).

I don't know why it's called "content.switch" or why a parser can be "interrupted" - it makes it sound like the process is single-threaded and Firefox is using user-threads, but I don't know Gecko.